# Windows 10 Autologon resets after switching user

Tags: windows-10, autologon

I have autologon enabled through netplwiz for one account (AppUser) on a Windows 10 PC with two accounts. If I switch to the second account, and restart the PC from there, autologon gets disabled for AppUser and the PC boots into the login screen like normal.

Is this intended behavior, a bug, or something else? Is there any way I can keep autologon enabled no matter which user shuts down the PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this through the registry, but only on computers where I'm not concerned about storing a plaintext password. There is a way to hash the password in the registry, but I never went through with completing it. Microsoft suggests using the Sysinternals tool called [AutoLogon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autologon).

Excerpt below quoted from: [Microsoft | Use Regedit to turn on Auto Login](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324737/how-to-turn-on-automatic-logon-in-windows)

> To use Registry Editor to turn on automatic logon, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click Start, and then click Run.
> 2. In the Open box, type Regedt32.exe, and then press Enter.
> 3. Locate the following subkey in the registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`
> 4. Double-click the DefaultUserName entry, type your user name, and then click OK.
> 5. Double-click the DefaultPassword entry, type your password, and then click OK.
>
> > NOTE: If the DefaultPassword value does not exist, it must be added. If no DefaultPassword string is specified, Windows automatically
> > changes the value of the AutoAdminLogon key from 1 (true) to 0
> > (false), disabling the AutoAdminLogon feature. To add the value,
> > follow these steps:
> >
> > 1. On the Edit menu, click New, and then point to String Value.
> > 2. Type DefaultPassword, and then press Enter.
> > 3. Double-click DefaultPassword.
> > 4. In the Edit String dialog, type your password and then click OK.
>
> 6. On the Edit menu, click New, and then point to String Value.
> 7. Type AutoAdminLogon, and then press Enter.
> 8. Double-click AutoAdminLogon.
> 9. In the Edit String dialog box, type 1 and then click OK.
> 10. If you have joined the computer to a domain, you should add the DefaultDomain value, and the data for the value should be set as the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the domain.
> 11. Exit
>     Registry Editor.
> 12. Click Start, click Shutdown, and then type a reason in the Comment text box.
> 13. Click OK to turn off your computer.
> 14. Restart your computer. You can now log on automatically.
>
> > Additional Notes:
>
> - To bypass the AutoAdminLogon process and to log on as a different user, press and hold the Shift key after you log off or after Windows
>   restarts.
> - This registry change does not work if the Logon Banner value is defined on the server either by a Group Policy object (GPO) or by a
>   local policy. When the policy is changed so that it does not affect
>   the computer, the autologon feature works as expected.
> - When Exchange Active Sync (EAS) password restrictions are active, the autologon feature does not work. This behavior is by design. This
>   behavior is caused by a change in Windows 8.1 and does not affect
>   Windows 8 or earlier versions. To work around this behavior in Windows
>   8.1 and later versions, remove the EAS policies in Control Panel.
> - An interactive console logon that has a different user on the server changes the DefaultUserName registry entry as the last
>   logged-on user indicator. AutoAdminLogon relies on the DefaultUserName
>   entry to match the user and password. Therefore, AutoAdminLogon may
>   fail. You can configure a shutdown script to set the correct
>   DefaultUserName.
> - You can use the Sysinternals tool AutoLogon to enable this functionality easier. This tool also helps you to use an encrypted
>   version of password.